# Why does my widget disappear when the node submission form returns an error?

Tags: entities

I am the maintainer of a Drupal contrib module, [Getlocations](http://drupal.org/project/getlocations), and I am seeing a [very odd problem](http://drupal.org/node/1404974) in Drupal 7.

If a File or Image field widget is included on a content type, the `getlocations_fields` widget no longer works when returned with a required error, although it does work on the initial form load.

Further investigation shows that the functions that deploy the map, JavaScript, and CSS are not being accessed when the page has errored so no JavaScript or CS related to Getlocations is loaded.

If I remove the upload widget, it works as expected.

I really have no idea why this is happening, there are no entries in php.log or in Watchdog. What's going on?

Comment: You have several thousand lines of code in your module: can you narrow down the issue?

Comment: in getlocations.module, line 627 function getlocations_setup_js()
is called by function getlocations_fields_getmap() in getlocations_fields.module line 1252
which is called by function getlocations_fields_field_widget_form() on line 984

These three functions do not appear to be called on the error reload although the form does appear, presumably from a cache. Caching is not enabled at all and the browser is not caching either